# Foundation one grid column width for all viewport?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

In Semantic UI, I could use `.four.wide.column` to make a `4/16` wide column on all devices / viewports.

But in Foundation, It seems like I have to use `.small-4.medium-4.large-4` to make sure the column has the same width on the different devices / viewports.

Is there anything like ... `.all-4` column width in Foundation so I don't have to use `.small-4.medium-4.large-4`?

```
<!-- Semantic UI -->
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
</div>

<!-- Foundation -->
<div class="grid-x">
    <!-- Is there a .all-4 class? -->
    <div class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it just `small-4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `<div class="small-4 cell"></div>` it will have the right size on all viewports.

The classes are always overwritten by the next higher one, e.g.: medium overwrites small

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Foundation XY Grid Docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html)

```css
.cell {
  background: #1779ba;
  color: #fefefe;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
  <div class="cell small-6">6 cells</div>
  <div class="cell small-6">6 cells</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x ">
  <div class="cell small-4">4 cells</div>
  <div class="cell small-4">4 cells</div>
  <div class="cell small-4">4 cells</div>
</div>
```

Or if you need, the older [Foundation float grid docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html). (These are now disabled by default, and were replaced in v6.4)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation-float.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-4">4</div>
  <div class="columns small-4">4</div>
  <div class="columns small-4">4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-6">3</div>
  <div class="columns small-6">9</div>
</div>
```